# Syntax to complete shared preferences for number of clicks count

Tags: java, android

Hi I just need a little bit of a helping hand in completing this shared preferences code I have.

Currently I have a class where I stored in the relevant code for SharedPreferences:

```
public class SharedPreferencesManager {

    private static final String APP_PREFS = "AppPrefsFile";
    private static final String NUMBER_OF_CLICKS = "numberOfClicks";

    private SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    private static SharedPreferencesManager instance;



    private SharedPreferencesManager(Context context) {
        sharedPrefs =
                context.getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    public static synchronized SharedPreferencesManager getInstance(Context context){
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new SharedPreferencesManager(context);

        return instance;
    }

    public void storeClicks(int count)
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, count);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public int getNumberOfClicks(){
        int clicksNumber = sharedPrefs.getInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, 0);
        return clicksNumber;
    }
}
```

I want to count the number of clicks for buttons jokes, poems and funnystories from the MainActivity class and the 'select another' button from the Content class. So if each button was clicked 4 times, the total click count should be 16.

I want to keep the number of clicks count even after the app is closed and re-open. It's just the syntax of the counting of the clicks I am unsure of. I think for main activity it is correct but I am unsure on how to store it for the Content class.

TO recap, count the number of clicks for all of those buttons mentioned and this number should be accessible and updated no matter which page the user is in.

Below is the Main Activity class:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    final Context context = this;

    int clicksCount = 0;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(context).storeClicks(clicksCount);


        Button jokesButton = findViewById(R.id.button_jokes);
        Button poemsButton = findViewById(R.id.button_poems);
        Button funnyStoriesButton = findViewById(R.id.button_funny_stories);


        jokesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicksCount++;
            }
        });

        poemsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicksCount++;
            }
        });

        funnyStoriesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clicksCount++;
            }
        });


}
```

Below is Content class:

```
public class Content extends AppCompatActivity{

    Button backButton;
    Button selectAnotherButton;
    TextView contentText;
    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_content);

        int clicksCount = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(context).getNumberOfClicks();

        backButton = findViewById(R.id.button_back);
         selectAnotherButton = findViewById(R.id.button_select_another);

        selectAnotherButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    clicksCount++;

                }
        });

            backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
                public void onClick (View v){
                finish();
            }
        });
    }




}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having the two methods `getNumberOfClicks()` and `storeClicks()` in your `SharedPreferencesManager`, you could only have one like this:

```
public void increaseClickCount() {
    int clickCount = sharedPrefs.getInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, 0);
    clickCount++;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putInt(NUMBER_OF_CLICKS, clickCount);
    editor.apply();
}
```

You call this on every click. No need for the activities to know about the clicks count.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final SharedPreferencesManager prefManager = SharedPreferencesManager.getInstance(context);    

    jokesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            prefManager.increaseClickCount();
        }
    });

    ...
}
```

Also there's no need to store your context as a global variable because your activity is already a context itself, you can just use `this` or `MainActivity.this` for a context.